# img src not locating image path

Tags: html, flask

I'm fairly new to web dev/Flask so sorry if my question is basic.

I have an image called logo2.png and somehow the HTML isn't finding it. I even put the image everywhere I thought the code would look but it still returns a 404 error.

My code to find the image is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>Pando WR NFL Stat Form</h2>
    <img src="/static/PandoLogo2.png" alt="PandoLogo">
    <p>Enter the stats for a wide receiver to see how much they're worth</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The file directory looks like: [directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gokra.png). routes.py creates an end point that renders index.html. The above code is inside index.html. I tried putting the specified image inside the static directory, templates directory, same directory as routes.py and even the parent directory with microblog.py which Flask uses to run the project. I've even tried an absolute path to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your file structure your image is named `pandoLogo2.png`, noting that `src` is case sensitive.

It's also recommended to use the static `url_for` function to get the url for the image src, in case the static folder for your project is moved:

```
... src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pandalogo2.png') }}" ...
```